# Can I use R to highlight some words background color in a paragraph?

Tags: r, text, background-color, keyword

I have some paragraphs, and for each paragraph, I have different key words. For example:

```
I am a student. I like machine learning...
```

Here my keywords are student and machine learning. I want to give them different colors such as red for student and yellow for machine learning. So, the result should be something like:

[image]

Can I use R to do this and how?

Also, I know Python can somehow do this. For example:

```
from spacy import displacy

doc = nlp('I just bought 2 shares at 9 a.m. because the stock went up 30% in just 2 days according to the WSJ')
displacy.render(doc, style='ent', jupyter=True)
```

In here, the result is:

[image]

But this looks like just for name entity. In my case, my keywords are extracted by myself. SO it might be different

Comment: Maybe...? What type of output are you trying to create?

Comment: Hey, I edited my question. Probably it is more clear now.

Comment: Maybe look at the [`crayon`](https://github.com/r-lib/crayon) package.

Comment: A little while ago I started writing [a package for that](https://github.com/JBGruber/highlightr). It's pretty experimental and only works with html output for now but maybe it serves your purpose.

Comment: Hey. It looks pretty cool. But when I try to install your package, I have such error message: Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  Timeout was reached: [api.github.com] Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds

Comment: Strange, I think it might be a problem with dependecies. Maybe try to install them first: `install.packages(c("stringi", "tibble")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I created [a small package](https://github.com/JBGruber/highlightr) for this purpose some time ago. It is still pretty experimental and can currently only be used in `RMarkdown` or it will open a browser window (Viewer Pane in Rstudio) to display the text when used interactivly.

```
# devtools::install_github("JBGruber/highlightr")
library(highlightr)
text <- "I am a student. I like machine learning..."
df <- data.frame(
  feature = c("student", "machine learning"),
  bg_colour = c("red", "yellow"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
dict <- as_dict(df)
highlight(text, dict)
```

[image]

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r , results='asis'}
library(highlightr)
text <- "I am a student. I like machine learning..."
df <- data.frame(
  feature = c("student", "machine learning"),
  bg_colour = c("red", "yellow"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
dict <- as_dict(df)
highlight(text, dict)
```
````

[image]

The package is built on some very straighforward manipulation of the html output:

```
# bg_colour
for (j in seq_along(dict$feature)) {
  text[i] <- stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(
    str = text[i],
    pattern = dict$feature[j],
    replacement = paste0("<span style='background-color: ",
                         dict$bg_colour[j], "'>",
                         dict$feature[j], "</span>"),
    opts_fixed = stringi::stri_opts_fixed(case_insensitive = case_insensitive)
  )
}
```

All I do here is adding `<span style='background-color: yellow'>` before a word that is highlighted and `</span>` after that word. When I have time I will do the same for LaTeX output and maybe more. The reason for using `stringi` here to do a simple replacement job is that it can be used case-insensitive while ignoring other regex.